# TIKZ: Layering Text over Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node, layers

I'd like to create a box in tikz that contains regular text, and underneath that text, another layer of text. I can create the first layer of regular text, but I'm stumped on how to put the lower layer into the box.

The effect I'm going for is this: [image: mock-up]

where the large numeral 1 should be behind the text. Here's the MWE of the regular text in the box (the format of the box needs to be as specified here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  every node/.style={%
    draw, %
    rectangle}, %
  text width=4cm, %
  minimum height=6\baselineskip]

\node{A bunch of text that is supposed to fill the box.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a semicolon missing and the `width` key does not exist (and wouldn't make sense since the `text width` is already 4cm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `1` on the background layer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  mynode/.style={%
    draw, %
    rectangle, %
  text width=4cm, %
  minimum height=6\baselineskip}]

\node[anchor=center,mynode] (txt){A bunch of text that is supposed to fill the box.};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[color=gray!40,scale=5,font=\sffamily] at (txt.center){1};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the box is not part of a `tikzfigure`, you could use `tcolorbox` and its `watermark image` or `watermark text` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    watermark text=Behind]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbox[enhanced, watermark text=Some text]{This is the text in the front}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    watermark color=red,
    watermark opacity=.5,
    watermark text=Behind]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]